# How do I change the washers of this tap?

Tags: plumbing

I have a tap. I am struggling to work out how to change the main washers. How do I get access to the main washers?

I can not identify the tap, so answer will probably be speculative. Just tell me what experience you have, and what you would do.

## What I have done so far.

I undid one bolt, and the front comes off.

[image: Over view of he taps]
[image: The tap handle after it is removed]

I believe that the two small washers that are visible in the 2nd photo (the one of the tap handle), are not the washers to turn the tap off. I think they are to stop leaks along the shaft.

Some experimenting upholds the hypothesis that the tap handle pushes and releases an inter hidden bit, that in turn blocks the flow of waster: By pushing the inner hidden bit, I can modulate the flow of water (this was done by setting the isolation tap, to restrict flow. So pressure was low).

Next I looked at what is now at the front (after the tap handle is removed).

[image: The mysterious hex]

## Option 1

There is what looks like a hex nut, but is it. I see not seam between this and the main body. Should I attach my grips and apply lots of force? Or is it just decorative?

## Option 2

Go in from the back.
[image: View of where the tap is attached]
If I remove both of the attachment bolts (I will need to isolate hot and cold, as same time, to do this), will I be able to gain access from the back?

---

Images licence cc-by-sa ctrl-alt-delor [How do I change the washers of this tap?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/198652/76435)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that is a hex nut at the front. don't use grips you could make a big mess. use a box or ring wrench of the appropriate size. or use an adjustable wrench but be careful.

I've tinted the part that comes off red and the part that stays blue
[image]

Comment: And cover it in blue tape first, to prevent nicking the finish.  Be gentle!

Comment: @Bryce I used red tape. It seemed to do the job.

Answer (score 2):

I may be missing something here.

The main washer for turning the hot and cold water off in this faucet setup is located at the end of the stem of the part you just pulled off.  The washer may have been worn so much that it is now gone.  But the washer is either a cone or a flat rubber or fibre washer that is held on the end by a screw.

If it still leaks after replacing the washer on the end, then the seat that the washer is pressed against may need to be replaced or resurfaced.  There is a stem tool that fits into that same hole, and does a polishing/filing of the seat to remove any nicks caused by a worn washer.  Replacement of the seat is done by using a tool, normally a hex wrench, and unscrewing the faucet seat.

[image]

Comment: There was a whole lot more, but under the other cover. The thread that you have highlighted is what push/pulls the bit with the washer.